# Different color names with same color values in some devices

Tags: android, colors

I have complaint from my user:

"When input text in MultiAutoCompleteTextView control -> color of text and background are same and I cannot read text!"

Actually I'm using colors provided from device.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"
    android:id="@+id/title_layout" android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/_Find" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_send" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send" android:text="@string/Search"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/search_city"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp" android:layout_below="@+id/title_layout"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:hint="@string/CityResort"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/search_address"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    >
    <requestFocus />
</MultiAutoCompleteTextView>

<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/search_address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_city"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:hint="@string/adres_or_poi_name"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Comment: Why do you need to set the colors if they are the ones provided by the device anyway?

Comment: Problem is in MultiAutoCompleteTextView. I dont set colors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be because of the different theme colors.
For eg. my motorola defy has the black theme therefore if you set white or black text on different native widgets, the background could be an unexpected one(like black and you set the text color to black) and the text can't be readable..
Try to set the theme of your application and maybe this will fix your problem.

Comment: Actualy from 20000 users only 1 complaint. Probably strange custom ROM with messed light/dark colors in temes. Who knows. I preffer to not set theme. It it good practice to use theme selected by user. They are selected certain theme.

Comment: I agree with you but in cases you do modify the theme color like setting a different color of a text on a native widget I think the best is to use a custom theme or to work on a native theme that you know its colors